# Image path null in Android

Tags: android

I have code like this, the problem is when i want to save it to `sqlite`, the error message shown that i got null in image path.
Here is the main activity

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                System.out.println("Data Image : "+selectedImageUri);
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                image1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            result = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your `startActivityForResult()` call for `SELECT_PICTURE`, plus the implementation of `getPath()`.

Comment: are you getting any value for Uri or that is null too?

Comment: just the image path is null

Comment: Instead of a path that is null just store `data.getData().toString()`. If you retrieve that string you can easily construct back that uri.

Comment: 'Data Image : content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A116230'
I have this after i print it

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to take photos from camera.

```
private void capturePhoto() {
// save this Uri in a field variable.
    uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new ContentValues());
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

then onActivityResult will look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        // use the field Uri, it now points to the path to the image taken from the camera.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In manifest file set permission
2. Check permission granted in `onActivityResult` method and after its granted `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
3. If it has Permission then call `doCreatePath()` and set the same in `onRequestPermissionsResult` on permission granted.

```
void doCreatePath()
 {

        try {

            Uri originalUri = filePath;
            String pathsegment[] = originalUri.getLastPathSegment().split(":");
            String id = pathsegment[0];
            final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            final String imageOrderBy = null;
            Uri uri = getUri();
            Cursor imageCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, imageColumns,
                    null, null, null);

            if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index_data = imageCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                realPath = imageCursor.getString(column_index_data);
                System.out.print("value" + realPath);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It works!.